# Unable to set a classname for React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the color of a tile in React Calendar after a click on a specific date but nothing happens. Default styling applies each time when the date is clicked. However, in static mode when there is no click event classname successfully changes. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import "./App.css"


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

  date :new Date(),
}
this.tileHandler = this.handleDayColors.bind(this);
  }




onDayClick = date => {

  return this.setState(
    {
      date: date,

    },
    () => {
      this.tileHandler = this.handleDayColors.bind(this); // here you reassign!
    }
  );
}

handleDayColors = ({ date, view }) => {  return view === 'month' &&  date === this.state.date ? 'red' : null}






  render()  {   

    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onClickDay = {this.onDayClick}
          tileClassName = {this.tileHandler}

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
} export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

use a state variable to assign `tileClassName` value.

```
<div>
     <Calendar
      onClickDay = {this.onDayClick}
      tileClassName = {this.state.color}
      />
</div>
```

and on  `handleDayColors` set the state value.

```
handleDayColors = this.setSetstate({color:'red'})
```